# Make nav fill out full width without breaking the website

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I wanted to know how I can make a nav menu I made fill out the whole page. A simple solution I thought of was to put it on absolute position and set top, left, bottom, right to 0. However, this caused it to go over the content and made the whole page a different color. Here's my HTML/CSS:

```js
//JS
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("nav-links");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
/* CSS */

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;
  background: white;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.topnav #nav-links {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
}

.topnav a.icon {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #b47b5a;
  color: white;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="script/server.js"></script>
  <title>Hello</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="#" class="active">Hello World!</a>
      <div id="nav-links">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="body">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </div>
  <script src="script/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried every method I could think of and search of, but can't really pull it off.

Comment: it looks like its working in your snippet? You could also try using `width: 100vw;` this will make the content 100% the width of the viewport its being loaded in

Comment: @JDawwgy I tried the width: 100vw and it enabled side-scrolling. The thing is, on the website (and I believe on the code snippet as well), there are gaps between the top, left, and right and the topnav.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to make the topnav position to absolute, it is the correct way. You just must to adjust the padding or margin of the content below the topnav or set the padding top to the body so the topnav is not to go over the content.

```js
//JS
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("nav-links");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
/* CSS */

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;
  background: white;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.topnav #nav-links {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
}

.topnav a.icon {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #b47b5a;
  color: white;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="script/server.js"></script>
  <title>Hello</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="#" class="active">Hello World!</a>
      <div id="nav-links">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="body">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </div>
  <script src="script/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Or you can make the topnav width to 100vw so the topnav will fully contain the width of your device, and set the body margin and padding to 0. But i not recomend to use this because sometimes it can make your website have horizontal scrolling, so the best way is still to use the first answer.

```js
//JS
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("nav-links");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
/* CSS */

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;
  background: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;      
  width: 100vw;
}

.topnav #nav-links {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
}

.topnav a.icon {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #b47b5a;
  color: white;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="script/server.js"></script>
  <title>Hello</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="#" class="active">Hello World!</a>
      <div id="nav-links">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="body">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </div>
  <script src="script/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```